# Best Practices for setting a config var during build or release

Tags: git, spring-boot, heroku, sentry

I've got a Spring Boot application that is hosted on Heroku and uses Sentry for error tracking.
I am trying to get release tracking sorted for the application and I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Ideally, I'd like to take the git hash heroku builds my app from, and assign that to a config var that will be picked up by Sentry when the application starts.

For example, I have config vars for sentry already:
`SENTRY_DSN` and `SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT`. I want another one, `SENTRY_RELEASE` - that I want to populate with some value that identifies that deployment, git hash being the most unique one I could think of.

But how do I populate that variable? I know that I can use the Heroku CLI to set a variable but I don't want to do that for every environment and every build, manually.

Heroku is already building the slug and deploying it, surely there is a way to hook into that process and populate a config var?

I could use the build number at the bottom of the log, v57 in this case, or the id in the top right, but I'd like it to actually refer to a commit:

[image: build_log]

Another approach could be to use Github Actions for this. I do CI on my dev branch. Would it be possible to add a webhook on the end of that build that sets the git hash as a config var?

While my master branch doesn't deploy automatically, I could add a webhook to that workflow as well and just set it to deploy master to production automatically and that would keep things in sync?

How are you populating environment variables as part of your release process? Keen to hear your thoughts!

Edit:
I've tried enabling dyno-metadata as it contains the git hash, but having done that and run `env` as per the article, I don't see any new environment variables - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

If I can get this stuff populated though, in theory it would be a case of taking the `HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT` provided by heroku dyno metadata and then storing that value as `SENTRY_RELEASE` - Heroku would then take care of the rest.

Comment: If you use a variable at **build** stage, generated artifact will work just in one environment (static values inside artifact). Is this what you need? Maybe a classic approach with variables at runtime could be a solution!

Comment: I think it's fine at build time because I need to uniquely identify an artifact, But the variable needs to be passed at run time, hence the use of config vars, I could set it at build time or run time, I don't think it changes anything

Comment: I you build a jar with a static value inside (var at build stage. String releaseId = "100" or a properties   releaseId=100), How will you pass a value at runtime if 100 is already setted?

Comment: Not sure I follow. If I've already settled the value at build time, I don't need to pass it in during run. If there was a way of telling Gradle to inject some variable (in this case the commit hash) at build time, that would be functionally the same as getting Heroku to apply it at run time.

Comment: What will be the advantage to set this var at build time? If this var changes, you must need to build again instead a simple restart if is used at runtime.